# Multi order by column, and criteria

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I got a problem ordering by columns. First i need to have it like it selects out here. but in the Olie i need to have it place after the "x.x" in way, and before the where way hasn't been set to anything, but it needed to be sorted after the text in the Hidden column.

My current Order by in SQL

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Way] = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, [Way]
```

//The Wrong Way (What it is now)

```
Hidden Colum                Pt  Way
Tilsætning_20_prioritet_01  0   0.3
Tilsætning_01_prioritet_01  1   1.0
Tilsætning_12_prioritet_01  1   1.0
Tilsætning_21_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_22_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_23_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_24_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_25_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_27_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_26_prioritet_01  3   3.0
Tilsætning_08_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_09_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_03_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_06_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_07_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Genbrug_prioritet_01        
Vand
```

The Right Way (what i need)

```
Hidden Colum                Pt  Way
Tilsætning_20_prioritet_01  0   0.3
Tilsætning_01_prioritet_01  1   1.0
Tilsætning_12_prioritet_01  1   1.0
Tilsætning_21_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_22_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_23_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_24_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_25_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_27_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_26_prioritet_01  3   3.0
Tilsætning_03_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_06_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_07_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_08_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_09_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Genbrug_prioritet_01        
Vand
```

Anyone have any clues, or ways i need to archive this?

***Edit***
 When tried

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Way] = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, Hidden Colum 

Tilsætning_01_prioritet_01  1   1.0
Tilsætning_02_prioritet_01  1   1.0
Tilsætning_03_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_04_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_05_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_06_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_07_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_08_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_09_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_10_prioritet_01  0   Olie
Tilsætning_11_prioritet_01  1   1.0
Tilsætning_12_prioritet_01  1   1.0
Tilsætning_13_prioritet_01  0   0.0
Tilsætning_14_prioritet_01  0   0.0
Tilsætning_15_prioritet_01  0   0.1
Tilsætning_16_prioritet_01  0   0.1
Tilsætning_17_prioritet_01  0   0.2
Tilsætning_18_prioritet_01  0   0.2
Tilsætning_19_prioritet_01  0   0.2
Tilsætning_20_prioritet_01  0   0.3
Tilsætning_21_prioritet_01  2   2.0
Tilsætning_22_prioritet_01  2   2.0
```

Comment: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Way] = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, [Way], HiddenColumn`?

Comment: Then olie will be put up in the numbers of way and it should not. so that won't work :/

Comment: Have you tried? (Way is still before in the ORDER BY...)

Comment: yes i have tried, and it oile ended up in between the way numbers, and messed up the sorting of way

Comment: Don't think so...

Comment: nm, i looked wrong, you totaly right :) can you make a answer, so i can mark it ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include HiddenColumn as last item in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [Way] = '' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, [Way], HiddenColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need the numbers in `Way`, then `'Olie'` and then everything else.

```
order by (case when Way not like '%[^0-9.]%' then 1
               when Way = 'Olie' then 2
               else 3
          end),
         pt,
         HiddenColumn
```